# Attempting to automate a task from Windows to Linux (BusyBox) Console that requires user interaction for termination

Tags: linux, powershell, esxi, plink, posh-ssh

I have a Powershell script that will automatically SSH to a Linux host (ESXI Server running Busybox) and will run a singular command (`./my_script.sh`), which captures some network traffic on the ESXI server. However, this script waits for user input (CTRL + C) to exit the script.

I have tried using the Posh-SSH module (`Invoke-SSHCommand -SSHSession $session -Command $command`) syntax as well as the Plink module (`plink -batch *servername* -pw *userPassword* *command*`) but the commands always execute and return me back to the shell, they never wait for user interaction.

Of course, if I run it directly on the ESXI server the script will wait for the CTRL + C command to terminate.

Does anybody know of a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

On option is the [`timeout`](https://ss64.com/bash/timeout.html) command which shuold be present on , to set a runtime limit for whatever command you are running. For example, if you needed `tcpdump` to capture packets for 20 seconds you could run:

```sh
timeout 20 tcpdump
```

You can also specify a specific signal to send to the process with the `--signal` flag, if the command you are using has inconsistent behavior across different signals (view a list of signals wit kill -l`):

```sh
timeout --signal INT 20 tcpdump
```

Comment: Is the --signal done within the powershell script or the linux script?

Comment: Linux, `--signal` is a flag on the timeout command: `timeout --signal INT 1 sleep 10` will send a SIGINT to the `sleep` process to kill it after 1 second. Updated answer to be more clear

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I need the script to run indefinitely until I tell it to stop. And I would also need it to be done using plink or posh-ssh as I'm running the script on linux from a powershell script.